# How to get only one else statement for nested if/else statements inside for loop in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

[image]

I want to get the else statement only if there is no word from the spam_word list matches the data.

Comment: Check if the `count == 0` and put the check after the for-loop.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Can we see the `emailSpam.txt` file?

Comment: Also please don't use images, use code when asking questions!

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very new to writing codes. For my next question, it wont be a image for sure.

Answer (score 2):

This was rewritten from your image, but the premise is to check your counter after the for loop.

If one hit is enough from the data, you could also "break" from the "for words in data" loop

```
count = 0
for word in spam_word:
    if word in data:
        print(word)
        count += 1

# after the for loop check if words were found
if count:
    # words found
    print("Spam word found ",count)
else:
    # words not found
    print("Email does not include any predefined spam words.")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about swapping the if condition:
. . .

```
if word not in data:
    print("Email does not include any predefined spam words.")
else:
    print(word)
    count += 1
```

. . .